# How to reuse Django's SQL compiler?

Tags: python, mysql, django

I needed to perform an `UPDATE JOIN` query but django has no builtin support for that, so I wrote a raw SQL query. But now I need to build the `where` clause of that query dynamically, so I would like to know how to reuse Django's SQL compiler.

I could take the `Query` object from `Model.objects.filter(...).query`, then generate the raw SQL of the where clause with `query.where.as_sql(query.get_compiler(using='default'), None)` but the tables from my current raw SQL are aliased, so the lookup fields will be wrong.

Comment: Have you considered pulling the ID's first, then doing an `update where id in (...)`?

Comment: @schillingt @schillingt django F-expressions does not works on reference to foreign fields, that's why `UPDATE JOIN` queries are not supported. To emulate that update join I need to run two subqueries for each row to be updated, that's not efficient.

Comment: I ended up writting my own compiler using string templates, this part of django is not documented, so it's hard to understand.

Comment: could you please share how to write your own compiler @hldev

Comment: @AlexanderPhung I just used raw queries (aka `Manager.raw()`) with template strings to format the raw SQL query. Django's internal code is not documented, it's hard to reason about it and do deep changes.